# F# Comment error

Tags: f#

I am teaching myself F# I am normally a C# programmer.

I am trying to use the `(**)` to make notes for myself as I go through the chapters but I am getting an error from the comment itself.

```
module Characters

let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

printfn "Hex u0061 = '%c'" '\u0061'

(*  <------------Error is here, is 'End of file in string embedded in comment begun at or before here'
    Character Escape Sequences

    Character       Meaning
    -------------------------------
    \'              Single Quote
    \"              Double Quote
    \\              Backslash
    \b              Backspace
    \n              Newline
    \r              Carriage Return
    \t              Horisontal Tab
*)
```

Is this treating the comment like a string meaning I have to escape my comment?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

F# trivia time!  This is by design.  [Block comments can be nested, and strings within a block comment are tokenized like regular strings](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818772).  Valid char literals count as "strings" in this case.

So these are valid block comments:

```
(* "embedded string, this --> *) doesn't close the comment" *)
(*  (* nested *) comment *)
(* quote considered to be in char literal '"' is ok *)
```

But these are not

```
(* "this string is not closed *)
(* " this quote --> \" is escaped inside a string *)
```

And as if that wasn't crazy enough, there is [special treatment for operators which begin with `*`](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818786) since `(*)` and the like would normally be considered the start or end of a block comment.

```
(* I can talk about the operator (*) without ending my comment *)
```

AFAIK, these are all inherited from ML (nested comments definitely are, not sure about strings).

So for your purposes, you might want to do something like this:

```
(*  Character       Meaning
    -------------------------------
    " \' "          Single Quote
    " \" "          Double Quote

    or

    '\''            Single Quote
    '"'             Double Quote
*)
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the "Double Quote" line is the problem. If I remove that line, the error goes away. This looks like a bug in the parser, since the problem does not occur if I prefix each line with `//` instead of doing a block-comment. I'd suggest you send this to fsbugs@microsoft.com - if it's not already fixed for Visual Studio 2013, maybe it's not too late.

Completely unrelated: your `vowels` list contains a single element that is a 5-part tuple. If you want it to be a list of characters instead of a list containing one 5-part tuple, use semicolons instead of commas.

Comment: But `(* "" *)` does not. It appears to want balanced double-quotes within block comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment also on the vowels but this is just an example from a book. just going with the flow right now.